# How to programmatically create ListView based off SQLite query?

Tags: android-listview, android-sqlite

I have some code that allows the user to perform a search by selecting a few checkboxes. A sql query is then created based on what checkboxes are checked. (Up to 5 checkboxes)

The data is then queried against a sqlite data.

The issue is now how do i populate the data into a listview (not knowing how many columns there will be ahead of time (Could be anywhere from 1 to 5)

All the examples I"ve seen is where the listView is created and you know exactly how many colummns are going to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous posted suggested to query all the records and then use if statements to determine if the value is null then hide column.